# TCP server with tasks

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm writing a TCP server using tasks and I wanted to know if there's something I can improve and how I am doing.

**ConnectionHandler.cs:**

```
public class ConnectionHandler
{
    private List<TClient> CLIENT_LIST;
    private TcpListener LISTENER;
    private const int PORT = 8080;
    private const int ACCEPT_DELAY = 75;

    public bool IsListening => LISTEN_FLAG;
    private bool LISTEN_FLAG = false;

    public ConnectionHandler()
    {
        LISTENER = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
        CLIENT_LIST = new List<TClient>();
    }

    public void StartListeningAsync()
        => Task.Run((Action)StartListening);

    public void StartListening()
    {
        LISTEN_FLAG = true;
        LISTENER.Start();
        while (LISTEN_FLAG)
        {
            Task.Run(() => CreateConnectionAsync(LISTENER.AcceptSocket()));
            Thread.Sleep(ACCEPT_DELAY);
        ]
        LISTENER.Stop();
            CLIENT_LIST.Clear();
        }


    public void StopListening()
        => LISTEN_FLAG = false;

    private void CreateConnectionAsync(Socket connectionSocket)
        => Task.Run(() => CreateConnection(connectionSocket));

    private void CreateConnection(Socket connectionSocket)
    {
        TClient CLIENT = new TClient(connectionSocket);
        CLIENT.DisconnectEvent += new TClient.ClientEvent(DisconnectEventHanlder);
        CLIENT_LIST.Add(CLIENT);
    }

    private void DisconnectEventHanlder(TClient sender)
        => CLIENT_LIST.Remove(sender);
 }
```

Here I start to accept the incoming connections, then I create a `TClient`class, add it to a `List` and add an event for the client disconnection.

**TClient.cs:**

```
public class TClient
{
    public delegate void Event();

    public delegate void DataEvent(IPacket data);
    public delegate void ClientEvent(TClient client);

    private int _SessionID;
    private bool _IsAvailable = true;
    private string _IPAdress;
    private Socket _connectionSocket;      

    public event ClientEvent DisconnectEvent;      
    public event DataEvent ProcessDataEvent;
    public event DataEvent SendDataEvent;

    public Socket ConnectionSocket => _connectionSocket;
    public string IPAdress => _IPAdress;
    public int SessionID => _SessionID;
    public bool IsAvailable => _IsAvailable;

    private PacketHandler PacketHandler;
    private PacketProcessor PacketProcessor;
    private ConnectionMaintenance Maintenance;

    public int ProcessedCorruptedPackets => PacketProcessor.CorruptedPackets;
    public int ReceivedCorruptedPackets => PacketHandler.CorruptedPackets;
    public int ReceivedData => PacketHandler.ReceivedData;
    public int ReceivedPackets => PacketHandler.ReceivedPackets;

    public TClient(Socket connection)
    {
        _SessionID = SessionFactory.GenerateUniqueSession();
        _connectionSocket = connection;
        _IPAdress = connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0];
        PacketHandler = PacketHandler.CreateHandler(this);
        PacketProcessor = PacketProcessor.CreateProcessor(this);
        Maintenance = ConnectionMaintenance.CreateConnectionMatinance(this);           
    }   


    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _connectionSocket.Close();
        _IsAvailable = false;
        DisconnectEvent(this);            
    }

    public void ProcessData(IPacket data)
        => ProcessDataEvent(data);

    public void SendData(IPacket data)
       => SendDataEvent(data);

    public void KeepAlive() => 
        Maintenance.AliveTime = 0;        

  }
```

This is were I store the socket and the other connection information, such as the IP address, session ID, other classes, and the events for sending data, and processing received data.

**PacketHandler.cs:**

```
public class PacketHandler
{
    private const short MAX_DATA_LENGTH = 1024;
    private const short LOOP_DELAY = 9;

    public int ReceivedPackets => _receivedPackets;
    public int ReceivedData => _receivedData;
    public int CorruptedPackets => _corruptedPackets;

    private int _corruptedPackets;
    private int _receivedPackets;
    private int _receivedData;

    private TClient CLIENT;
    public static PacketHandler CreateHandler(TClient client) => new PacketHandler(client);
    private PacketHandler(TClient client)
    {
        CLIENT = client;
        CLIENT.SendDataEvent += new TClient.DataEvent(SendPacket);         
        Task.Run(() => ReceiveDataLoop(CLIENT));        
    }  
    private void ReceiveDataLoop(TClient CLIENT)
    {
        while (CLIENT.IsAvailable)
        {
            try
            {
                ReceivePacket();                   
            }
            catch
            {
                CLIENT.Disconnect();                   
            }
            Thread.Sleep(LOOP_DELAY);
        }            
    }
    private void SendPacket(IPacket data)
    {
        CLIENT.ConnectionSocket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)data.Length));
        CLIENT.ConnectionSocket.Send(data.PacketData);
    }        
    private void ReceivePacket()
    {
        byte[] lengthHeader = new byte[2];
        CLIENT.ConnectionSocket.Receive(lengthHeader);
        ushort DataLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(lengthHeader, 0);
        byte[] PacketHeader = new byte[1];           
        CLIENT.ConnectionSocket.Receive(PacketHeader);
        byte[] data = new byte[DataLength];
        CLIENT.ConnectionSocket.Receive(data);        
        if (data.Length > MAX_DATA_LENGTH) _corruptedPackets++;
        else
        {
            CLIENT.ProcessData(new IPacket(PacketHeader[0], data));
            _receivedData += DataLength;
            _receivedPackets++;
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Here is were the data is received and sent. First I receive Ushort that indicates the length of the data received, then a byte that indicates what will the program have to when it's processed. This data is then passed to an `IPacket`.

```
public struct IPacket
{
    private byte _packetHeader;
    private byte[] _packetData;

    public byte[] PacketData => _packetData;
    public byte PacketHeader => _packetHeader;
    public int Length => _packetData.Length;

    public IPacket(byte _header, byte[] _data)
    {
        _packetData = _data;
        _packetHeader = _header;
    }       
}
```

Then this is converted to an `IMessage`:

```
public enum Header
{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    CORRUPTED = 1,
    KEEP_ALIVE = 2
}
public struct IMessage
{

    private IPacket basePacket;
    private Header _header;
    public string DataString => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(basePacket.PacketData);
    public Header Header => GetHeader();

    public IMessage(IPacket _basePacket)
    {
        basePacket = _basePacket;
        _header = Header.UNKNOWN;
    }
    private Header GetHeader()
    {
        if (_header != Header.UNKNOWN)
            return _header;
        if (basePacket.PacketHeader == 0)
            return Header.KEEP_ALIVE;
        else return Header.CORRUPTED;
    }
}
```

This is what will process the messages:

```
public class PacketProcessor
{
    public int CorruptedPackets => _corruptedPackets;       

    private int _corruptedPackets;
    private TClient CLIENT;

    public static PacketProcessor CreateProcessor(TClient client) => new PacketProcessor(client);
    private PacketProcessor(TClient client)
    {
        CLIENT = client;
        CLIENT.ProcessDataEvent += new TClient.DataEvent(ProcessMessage);
    }        
    private void ProcessMessage(IPacket Packet)
    {
        IMessage message = new IMessage(Packet);
        if (message.Header == Header.KEEP_ALIVE)
            CLIENT.KeepAlive();
        else if (message.Header == Header.CORRUPTED)            
            _corruptedPackets++;                   
    }
}
```

Then the connection is checked for exessive data flow, corrupted packets and no keep alive here:

```
public class ConnectionMaintenance
{
    public int AliveTime { get; set; }

    private const short LOOP_DELAY = 250;
    private const short MAX_DATA_PER_TICK = 960;
    private const short MAX_PACKETS_PER_TICK = 32;
    private const short MAX_CORRUPTED_PACKETS = 50;
    private const short MAX_ALIVE_MS = 15000; 

    private TClient CLIENT;
    public static ConnectionMaintenance CreateConnectionMatinance(TClient client) => new ConnectionMaintenance(client);

    private ConnectionMaintenance(TClient client)
    {
        CLIENT = client;
        new Task(MaintenanceLoop).Start();
    }

    private void MaintenanceLoop()
    {                     
        int lastReceivedData = 0;
        int lastReceivedPackets = 0;                   
        while (CLIENT.IsAvailable)
        {
            if (CLIENT.ProcessedCorruptedPackets >= MAX_CORRUPTED_PACKETS
            || CLIENT.ReceivedCorruptedPackets >= MAX_CORRUPTED_PACKETS)
                CLIENT.Disconnect();
            else if ((CLIENT.ReceivedData - lastReceivedData) >= MAX_DATA_PER_TICK)
                CLIENT.Disconnect();
            else if ((CLIENT.ReceivedPackets - lastReceivedPackets) >= MAX_PACKETS_PER_TICK)
                CLIENT.Disconnect();
            else if (AliveTime >= MAX_ALIVE_MS)
                CLIENT.Disconnect();
            else
            {
                AliveTime += LOOP_DELAY;
                lastReceivedData = CLIENT.ReceivedData;
                lastReceivedPackets = CLIENT.ReceivedPackets;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(LOOP_DELAY);          
        }
    }

}
```

I am worried about the structure of the program. Should I be using the async methods provided by the TCP classes?

I'm trying to make everything like "modules" so if I can update the code without affecting much each other "module". Then I'm using a lot of private variables with public get accesors. Is this worth it? Or should I just use public variables?

As I'm trying to keep things "modular", it doesn't feel right, since everything is dependent on `TClient` and the other classes are interconnected through it.

Answer (score 1):

**Names Names Names**

*Members*

We don't use UPPER_CASE in C# at all. Ok, I could live with UPPER_CASE `const` names but other members or even function parameters are a no-go. To me it looks like everything was a constant. It's very hard to read.

You are also not consistant because some members have almost correct names like `_SessionID` that actaully should be `_sessionId`.

*Classes*

We don't use the `T` prefix for type names. They are *reserved* for generic placeholders like `Client<T>`.

*Structs*

We don't use the `I` prefix for struct names. We use it only for interface names like `IEnumerable`.

---

**LISTEN_FLAG**

Try to name your variables so that they describe the class/object the are in. In this case it would be more appropriate to call it `IsListening`.

Comment: Thanks for asking. My naming is really bad, for  `TClient` I don't know what to call it, if I just call it "Client" then what do I call the variable? Similar thing happens with private variables ("_SessionID"), should I use the name of the publig adding `_` or should I call it something different?